# Unique values in same column from 2 unrelated tables in mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

I have 2 tables called 'parents' and 'children'.

---

### parents

parent_id | name |

---

### children

child_id | parent_id | child_name |

I am looking for a query which gives the output like so:

`parent_id(from parents) | name (unique names from both tables) | is_parent (1, if record is from parent table).`

I tried using following from one of the stacks:

```
SELECT
   T1.name, T2.child_name
FROM
   parents T1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   children T2 ON T1.name = T2.child_name
UNION
SELECT
   T1.name, T2.child_name
FROM
   parents T1
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   children T2 ON T1.name = T2.child_name
```

But it gives be 2 separate columns and not a merged, single column.

Appreciate your help.

---

Edit

---

Adding example:

[image]

Comment: please elaborate more with a table sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for joins, just UNION ALL:

```
select parent_id, name, 1 is_parent from Parents
union all
select parent_id, child_name, 0 from Children
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xsqEWxqmQKwm1YTzvYuLa7/0).
Results:

```
| parent_id | name    | is_parent |
| --------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1         | Raja    | 1         |
| 2         | Sahil   | 1         |
| 3         | Ramesh  | 1         |
| 4         | Suresh  | 1         |
| 1         | Riya    | 0         |
| 1         | Rakesh  | 0         |
| 2         | Abhay   | 0         |
| 2         | Vishnu  | 0         |
| 3         | Rakesh  | 0         |
| 3         | Sunitha | 0         |
```